# Final URL (after following all redirections) in the console

Tags: bash, shell

This URL:

```
https://httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/3
```

redirects to:

```
https://httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/2
```

then redirects to:

```
https://httpbin.org/get
```

What shell command can I use to get the final URL?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this at the moment:

```
curl -sS -L -I -o /dev/null https://httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/3  -w %{url_effective}'\n'
```

My first attempt is worth mentioning. It can be modified to display all redirections, if you remove this part `tail -1`:

```
curl -sS -v -o -L -I /dev/null https://httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/3 2>&1 | grep Locat | tail -1 | cut -c 13-3000
```